# Find the equations of circles passing through $(1, -1)$ touching the lines $4x+3y+5=0$ and $3x-4y-10=0$

Tags: geometry, circles, transformation

> Find the equations of circles passing through $(1,-1)$ touching the lines $4x+3y+5=0$ and $3x-4y-10=0$

The point of intersection of the lines is $(\frac25,-\frac{11}5)$

If we want this point of intersection to be $(0,0)$ (because the given lines are perpendicular) then define the new $X=x-\frac25,Y=y+\frac{11}5$, where $x,y$ are the original coordinates.

So, the point $(1,-1)$ in the new system becomes $(\frac35,\frac65)$. Since it's in the first quadrant, so, the center of the circle will be $(r,r)$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle.

So, $(\frac35-r)^2+(\frac65-r)^2=r^2\implies r=\frac35,3$

So, the equations of circles are $$(X-\frac35)^2+(Y-\frac35)^2=\frac9{25}\implies(x-1)^2+(y+\frac85)^2=\frac9{25}$$

and $$(X-3)^2+(Y-3)^2=9\implies(x-\frac{17}5)^2+(y-\frac45)^2=9$$

Is this correct?

Comment: If you solve the obtained circle equations with the line equations simultaneously it will be clear that the lines are not "touching" those circles.

Comment: What do you mean by "touching" the circles? Is it supposed to mean they are tangent? If so, then these circles do not work.

Comment: @Nick I guess by touching, they meant tangents.

Comment: I think you are imagining that, after switching to the coordinates X and Y, the lines are the X and Y axes.  You seem to be ignoring the fact that the lines are tilted.

Comment: @DanVelleman yes, but aren't they tilted at right angle? So, can't we take that as coordinate axes?

Comment: @aarbee try to find out what happened to lines after shifting them?

Comment: @IITM After shifting, did the lines not behave as coordinate axes?

Comment: @aarbee consider the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$,they are perpendicular and pass through origin,but they do not behave as co-ordinate axes unless they are rotated

Comment: @IITM oh, I see your point now. I needed to rotate the lines as well and not just shift the origin. Thanks. I'll reattempt.

Comment: @aarbee Just plug in your substitution: Your first line is $4(X+2/5) + 3(Y-11/5)+5=0$, which simplifies to $Y = (-4/3)X$. This is definitely not one of the coordinate axes.

Comment: @Nick got it, thanks. I'll reattempt now.

Comment: @aarbee These are the solutions https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rnxh51ihib

Comment: @IITM thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, the original lines are not parallel to coordinate axes. So if you want them to be coordinate axes, you will need rotation, in addition to shifting of origin. Instead you can find the equation of lines in new coordinate system after shifting the origin and complete the work using your approach.

In my answer, I am sharing another approach for this specific problem -

[image]

**First**, given that both lines are tangent to the circle and intersect at a point, we know that the center of the possible circles is on angle bisector of both lines.

Angle bisector of both lines is given by,

$4x+3y+5 = \pm(3x-4y-10)$ and we get two equations,

$y = - \dfrac{x}{7} - \dfrac{15}{7} \ $ and $ \ y = 7x-5$

Now we know x-intercept of $4x+3y+5=0 \ $ is $ - \dfrac{5}{4}$ and of $3x-4y-10=0$ is $\dfrac{10}{3}$. Given x-coordinate of point $(1, -1)$ being between the two x-intercepts, we know that the slope of angle bisector that we choose has to be between the slopes of tangent lines. That leads to the center of circles being on $y = 7x-5$.

So if radius of circle is $r$ and center is $(h, k)$, equating distance between center and $(1, -1)$,

$(h-1)^2 + (7h-4)^2 = r^2 \ \ $ ...$(i)$
$k = 7h-5 \ \ $ ...$(ii)$

**Second** we find distance from point $(1, -1)$ to both tangent lines. We have, $|d_1| = \dfrac{6}{5}, |d_2| = \dfrac{3}{5}$

As both tangent lines are perpendicular to each other, we know that (*refer diagram for clarification*)

$\left(\dfrac{6}{5}- r\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{3}{5}-r\right)^2 = r^2 \implies r = 3, \dfrac{3}{5}$

Plugging both values of $r$ into $(i)$, we can find values of $h$ and then $k$ from $(ii)$.

Now for each value of $r$, $(i)$ gives us a quadratic in $h$ so that will return two values. We can test which one works. To do that, we can check distance to tangent lines from $(h, k)$ should be equal to radius. But as we know the intersection point of tangent lines is $\left(\dfrac{2}{5}, -\dfrac{11}{5}\right)$, we can simply test

$ \left(h - \dfrac{2}{5}\right)^2 + \left(k + \dfrac{11}{5}\right)^2 = 2 r^2$ should be true (*refer diagram for clarification*).

Finally we get equation of two circles as,

$(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2 = 9 \ $ and $ \ \left(x-\dfrac{13}{25}\right)^2 + \left(y + \dfrac{34}{25}\right)^2 = \dfrac{9}{25}$

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate on the following please? "Given $x$-coordinate of point $(1,−1)$ being between the two $x$-intercepts, we know that the slope of angle bisector that we choose has to be between the slopes of tangent lines."

Comment: The slope is $\tan \theta$ where $\theta$ is measured from x-axis, correct? Now for the point $(1, -1), x = 1$ which is between x-intercepts of tangent lines. So for the circle to be tangent to both lines and also pass through point $(1, -1)$, it has to be between both tangent lines in the region where they intersect x-axis. So far with me?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes, I understood upto this point.

Comment: Sorry now I was away :) ok so as the center is on angle bisector of both tangent lines, the angle bisector will make a bigger angle with x-axis than one of the lines and less angle with x-axis than the other line.

Comment: Now for the given tangent lines, $m_1 = \frac{3}{4}$ and $m_2 = - \frac{4}{3}$ so I choose angle bisector with slope $7$ as it gives  greater slope than $m_1$ and less slope than $m_2$.

Comment: got it now, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Also given tangent lines are perpendicular, this method gives you $r$ very quickly otherwise you have to go by making standard system of equations to solve.

Answer (score 2):

We can try as follows:

Let $O(h,k)$ be the centre and $r$ be the radius

So, $r=\sqrt{(1-h)^2+(-1-k)^2}$

Again as the distance of a tangent from the centre is equal to the radius

$$r=\dfrac{|3h-4k-10|}5=\dfrac{|4h+3k+5|}5$$

From the last relation, we can find $k$ in terms of $h$

We can replace that value of $k$ in $$\sqrt{(1-h)^2+(-1-k)^2}=\dfrac{|3h-4k-10|}5$$

Take square in both sides to find $h$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: The point on the circle is $(1,-1)$,not $(1,1)$

Comment: @IITM, thanks for your observation

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, $|3h-4k-10|=|4h+3k+5|$ gives us two relations in $h,k$. How do we eliminate one?

Comment: @aarbee, Don't need to eliminate.  We need to handle each case separately.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,I think we can eliminate one so that we no need to struggle,with two equation see the diagram(I don't know how I can explain that so I am linking the diaagram) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/scnbij7jbj

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to find radius from @Math Lover's solution

if $(h,k)$ is center of circle ,then it's radius is given by the perpendicular distance of $(h,k)$ from any tangent

so,

$$r=\frac{|4h+3k+5|}{5}$$

from equation ($ii$) (see Math Lover's answer)

$$r=\frac{|4h+3(7h-5)+5|}{5}$$

$$ \implies  r=|5h-2| ...(iii)$$

substituting in equation ($i$) we get $h=1,\frac{13}{25}$,from equations ($ii$) and ($iii$) we get  $k,r$ also.I hope you can continue

Answer (score 1):

Geometric approach.
The centers of all inscribed circles are located on a bisector line,
which equation is $y=7x-5$.

Construct auxiliary inscribed circle, say centered at $O=(2,9)$
with the radius $r=8$.

[image]

The line $XP$ intersect this circle at
points $D(2,1)$ and $E(\tfrac{42}5,\tfrac{49}5)$
and we have two scaling coefficients,

\begin{align}
k_1&=\frac{|XP|}{|XE|}
=\tfrac3{40}
,\\
\text{and }\quad
k_2&=\frac{|XP|}{|XD|}
=\tfrac38
,
\end{align}
so we can find the centers and the radii of sought circles through $P$
as
\begin{align}
O_1&=X+(O-X)\cdot k_1
=(\tfrac{13}{25},-\tfrac{34}{25})
,\\
r_1&=r k_1=\tfrac35
,\\
O_2&=X+(O-X)\cdot k_2
=(1,2)
,\\
r_2&=r k_2=3
.
\end{align}

Then the circle equations would be

\begin{align}
(x-\tfrac{13}{25})^2+(y+\tfrac{34}{25})^2&=\tfrac9{25}
\\
\text{and }\quad
(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2&=9
.
\end{align}